# Not able to implement reset functionality on my component

Tags: reactjs

I have the following react component

```
  class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
     constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {registration: {firstName: "", lastName: "", activity: "", restrictions: ""}}
     }
     handleFirstNameChange(event) {
        var newRegistration = Object.assign({}, this.state.registration, {firstName: event.target.value})
        this.setState({registration: newRegistration})
     }
     handleLastNameChange(event) {
        var newRegistration = Object.assign({}, this.state.registration, {lastName: event.target.value})
        this.setState({registration: newRegistration})
     }  
     handleActivitySelect(newAct) {
        var newRegistration = Object.assign({}, this.state.registration, {activity: newAct})
        this.setState({registration: newRegistration})
     }      
     handleRestrictionsSelect(restrictions) {
        var newRegistration = Object.assign({}, this.state.registration, {restrictions: restrictions})   
        this.setState({registration: newRegistration})
     }
     saveRegistration() {
        this.props.handleChange(this.state.registration)
        this.setState({registration: {firstName: "", lastName: "", activity: "", restrictions: ""}}, () => {
           console.log(this.state.registration)
        })
     }
     render() { 
        var style = {
           padding: "15px 60px"
        }
        return (
           <div>
              <div>
                 <label> First Name:
                    <input type="text" id="firstname" onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this)}/>
                 </label>
              </div>
              <div>
                 <label> Last Name:
                    <input type="text" id="lastname" onChange={this.handleLastNameChange.bind(this)} />
                 </label>
              </div>
              <RegistrationActivity handleChange={this.handleActivitySelect.bind(this)} activities={["Science Lab", "Swimming", "Cooking", "Painting"]} />
              <RegistrationSpecialNeeds handleChange={this.handleRestrictionsSelect.bind(this)} restrictions={[{key: "a", name: "Dietary Restrictions"}, {key: 'b', name: 'Physical Disabilities'}, {key: 'c', name: 'Medical Needs'}]} />
              <button style={style} onClick={this.saveRegistration.bind(this)}>Submit</button>
           </div>
        )
     }
  }
```

The save registration method works as expected. it calls the parent method which was passed in this.props.handleChange.

The code also prints the following

```
[Log] {firstName: "", lastName: "", activity: "", restrictions: ""} (Registration.html, line 350)
```

So it is indeed blanking out the registration state.

But in the UI I still see the values which were filled. (so there were not blanked out.

There are two questions I have

1. In the code above, the content of the two text boxes is directly tied to the state and when the state is blanked out, the two text boxes (first name and last name) should have blanked out
2. The two child components, RegistrationSpecialNeeds and RegistrationActivity. How do I inform them that they should reset their internal state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. The text boxes aren't controlled components. You're only picking up the values because you're hooked onto the change event. You'll need to bind the value to the state of the component.

   `<input type="text" id="firstname" value={this.state.firstName} onChange={this.handleFirstNameChange.bind(this)}/>`

Have a read about controlled components here: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html

2. RegistrationSpecialNeeds and RegistrationActivity will re-render if the props change. Since the props you've defined are static (and not tied the state of the RegistrationForm component, they will not re-render when saving the form.

Comment: Your answer is correct ... but I even after moving to props for activity list. My reset functionality is not working. My code is a little long so I cannot post it here. If possible, have a look https://github.com/abhsrivastava/learn-react/blob/master/Registration.html

Comment: Is there any reason the RegistrationActivity has it's own internal state? It's best to manage the form state in a single place i.e. the RegistrationForm component. This way you clear all state in a one place after saving. Try removing the RegistrationActivity state and passing the value as a prop.

Comment: OK. it works after centralizing all state under the main App. thanks a lot!